# Browser prompting for login after enabling WAS application security

Tags: security, websphere, wcs

We have a websphere commerce application running on WAS 7. After enabling global security and application security,on accessing the application url , the browser prompts for login...only after logging in using the server admin credentials,the request is served..is this the expected behaviour of enabling security??

Comment: Security is a big subject with a lot of potential configurations, but that sounds like it's probably expected.    But this isn't a very helpful question.   It's not like anyone could look at this and confirm their own configuration was secure or insecure.   So I'm just giving you a "you're probably in the ballpark" answer but don't take this as confirmation that you're using security correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior. After enabling global and application security, access to application is enforced, if it has security configured in deployment descriptor.

Regarding admin credentials - you are probably using default file registry, with single admin user.  You can change who is authorized to access application in the application details page, clicking `Map user for security roles`. You can specify users, groups, or special subjects like `all authenticated` and `everyone`- which would allow to access your app without login, if you really want that.